# Incorrect date using pd.to_datetime in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm extracting some data from my Redshift database into a Pandas dataframe. 
The timestamp I have is:

`1529572553619`

When I convert it to date, the following happens:

`pd.to_datetime(1529572553619)`

Returns

`Timestamp('1970-06-27 00:48:45.536190')`

and

`pd.to_datetime(1529572553619*1000000)`

Returns

`Timestamp('2018-06-21 09:15:53.619000')`

However, the actual date is

`06/25/2018 @ 1:05pm (UTC)`

Any idea why I get the incorrect date?

Thanks

Comment: You are wrong about what that timestamp means.  https://www.epochconverter.com/ says it is the 25th like Pandas says, not the 21st like you say it should be.

Comment: I got the 21st using epochconverter as well. If the offset on your timestamps is constant, you could use the `datetime.timedelta` method to correct it

Comment: Yea, exactly. Pandas says it's the 21st (Timestamp('2018-06-21 09:15:53.619000')). Epochconcerter.com says it's the 25th

Comment: But shouldn't pandas get the 25th by default as well? Why do I have to use datetime.timedelta?

Comment: Where is this unix timestamp coming from in RedShift? Sounds like it could be a process issue, rather than an explicit python issue